# opening login form as pop-up in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using this function to redirect login page to my desired page in wordpress. I have pasted this code in my theme's functions.php file

```
function custom_login_page() {
 $new_login_page_url = home_url( '/login-2/' ); // new login page
 global $pagenow;
 if( $pagenow == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    wp_redirect($new_login_page_url);
   //($new_login_page_url);
    exit;
 }
}

if(!is_user_logged_in()){
 add_action('init','custom_login_page');
}
```

Now it is redirecting properly , but i am not getting how to open it as pop-up window? can somebody suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this... Inside window.open, first argument is what would you like to open in new window and the next argument is the size and position of the new window

```
function custom_login_page() {
 $new_login_page_url = home_url( '/login-2/' ); // new login page
 global $pagenow;
 if( $pagenow == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $link = "<script>window.open($new_login_page_url, '_blank', 'width=710,height=555,left=160,top=170')</script>";

echo $link;
    exit;
 }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried this, but its not happening. it gets redirected to the page instead of pop-up

Comment: Does it redirect inside the same browser tab?

Comment: Yes it is redirecting in same tab

Comment: Can somebody please help me in this?

Comment: I have updated my answer with second parameter in window.open being '_blank'. Could you please try that?

Comment: No, its not working and i have to create some short-codes then have to use in this function i guess. i fee It won't work in this way